# Spring-boot application gets stuck on startup randomly

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

Spring-boot application gets stuck on startup randomly at:

[image]
The postgres gets started then it gets stuck.
Only one log from the Java application is:
`Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000`

It's a brand new application. I am using spring-boot 2.6.6, Spring 5.3.18, JDK 17, and Hibernate 5.6.7.Final with docker-compose.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgis:11-alpine
    command: postgres -c stats_temp_directory=/tmp
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password!
      - POSTGRES_USER=xxx
      - POSTGRES_DB=xxx
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      xxx-network:

  fargate-xxx:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
    image: fargate-xxx-local-build
    build:
      context: ""
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    - 8000:8000
    networks:
      xxx-network:
    dns:
    - 8.8.8.8
    - 8.8.4.4
    environment:
      ENVIRONMENT: ${ENVIRONMENT}
      JAVA_OPTS: -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
    volumes:
    - ./dynamicconfig.properties:/tmp/dynamicconfig.properties


volumes: {}

networks:
  xxx-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine

EXPOSE 8000

COPY app.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar app.jar
```

BTW, I'm on M1.

Comment: `JAVA_OPTS: -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n` - have you tried removing that?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thanks for reminding me. Never suspected that one since the suspend is NO. Will try.

Comment: I have noticed `suspend=n`, however I think it worth to try disable debugger

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov I've tried that. It didn't work. Thanks.